# Rspec user controller - NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm now making Rspec test for `users_controller.rb`. However I'm in trouble the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_url'` as follow.

```
 FF

Failures:

1) UsersController PUT update user update does not succeed
 Failure/Error: put :update, {:id => user.to_param}, valid_session, :user_route => user
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersController:0x52e40e0>
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in update'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `update'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top      (required)>'

2) UsersController PUT update user update succeeds
 Failure/Error: put :update, {:id => user.to_param}, valid_session, :user_route => user
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersController:0x53bc560>
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in update'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `update'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.679 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:61 # UsersController PUT update user update does not succeed
 rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:56 # UsersController PUT update user update succeeds

 Randomized with seed 33412
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
     else
        format.html { render action: "user#edit" }
        format.json { render json: @idea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
  end
 end
end
```

Also here is my Rspec `users_controller_spec.rb`. I made two tests about "POST update". One is for being updated successfully. Another is for not being updated. (About the latter, I put the stub `User.stub(:update_attribute).and_return(false)` which I expect that "update_attribute" returns "false" so that process proceeds to "else".)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  let(:valid_attributes) { {
    "email" => "hoge@hogehoge.com",
    "password" => "12345678"
  } }

  def valid_session
    {}
  end

  describe "PUT update" do
    it "user update succeeds" do
      user = User.create! valid_attributes
      put :update, {:id => user.to_param}, valid_session
      assigns(:user).should eq(user)
    end
    it "user update does not succeed" do
      user = User.create! valid_attributes
      User.stub(:update_attribute).and_return(false)
      put :update, {:id => user.to_param}, valid_session
      assigns(:user).should eq(user)
      response.should render_template("edit")
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea to solve this, because I cannot understand where `user_url` did come. So I would like to have your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `redirect_to @user`, rails sends that request to `UsersController#show`, but it does so by calling `user_url(@user)`.  If I had to guess, you probably don't have the line that defines `user_url`:

```
resources :users
```

in your routes.rb file. This would automatically create the named route `user_url` that your controller is referencing with `redirect_to @user`

Alternatively, you could define the route yourself in your routes.rb file like so:

```
get "/users/show" => "users#show", as: :user
```

But that's not really the 'Rails-y' way to do it.  At any time, you can run the command `rake routes` in the terminal to see all the named routes you have defined in your `routes.rb` file.  If `user` isn't there, then you need to define it like I mentioned above.

More info on named routes here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devise then check if the following method returns anything.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
```

in application_controller.rb

If the method returns nothing you will receive the error:

undefined method `user_url' for #

I also ended up removing

```
stored_location_for(resource)
```

in after_sign_in_path_for(resource) because it was causing an endless loop. Refer to this answer for details.

[rails:3 Devise signup Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered/21970349#21970349)