# Filter chain halted error with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise with rails. I have generated User model in devise and I didn't have user controller and home controller . My root page is `devise/sessions#new`.

My root path

```
 devise_scope :user do
   root :to => "users/sessions#new"
 end
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

when I run localhost:3000 I am getting the following error.

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected. 

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-19 10:07:46 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

The solution I found on internet is that add this in sessions controller `prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]` . My doubt is how can I access sessions  controller. It is not generated in controller it is inbuilt module or is there any other way to solve this.

**app/controller/users/session_controller.rb**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
end
```

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: @IshankGupta- This is not I expected. When I run localhost:3000 it is not redirecting to my root path. When I want to login via omniauth callbacks it does not returning to correct path. says too many redirects. The webpage at http://localhost:3000/ has resulted in too many redirects.

Answer (score 3):

You can override session controller like this:

**route.rb**

```
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "users/sessions#new"
end
```

**app/controller/users/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
end
```

Comment: @vanda- I am once again getting the same error. I have updated what I ve done

Comment: @Jeff This happens because you already signed in. use `skip_before_filter` instead of `prepend_before_filter` look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered) and [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/974)

Comment: I found the real error. In root path I should not give sign in path. I need to mention some other path