# Rails 4 - Devise, guest users causes filter chain halted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I have just started working on a Rails 4 (4.2.3) app where I use `Devise` for user authentication. I want users to be able to play around with the app before signing upp by creating a test project and be signed in as a guest user. When the user signs up (or in) I want to assign the test project to the new current user.

I have been following this guide from Platformatec: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Creating the guest user works, but when signing up or in with an active guest user session I get the following error:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

If I clear my session it works. The method that manages my guest user looks like this:

```
def current_or_guest_user
  if current_user
    if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
      logging_in
      guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)
      session[:guest_user_id] = nil
    end
    current_user
  else
    guest_user
  end
end
```

As mentioned, creating guest users seems to work just fine. But this logic never happens:

```
# should delete the guest user and clear the session. 
if current_user
  if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
    logging_in
    guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)
    session[:guest_user_id] = nil
  end
  current_user
```

I'm pretty sure that my guest user session is conflicting with my new user and causes this Devise error (since the guest user never gets deleted on sign up):

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

The rest of my guest user logic looks more or less exactly like this linked guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user. I also added the code from the Authentication paragraph / example: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user#authentication-this-may-interfere-with-the-current_user-helper.

Any ideas on what I'm missing, and how I can get my `current_or_guest_user` to delete the guest user on signup and signing when using Devise?

**Update**

This is how my routes look currently:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations:  "users/registrations" }

root :to => 'public#index'

resources :apps

get 'users/show', to: "users#show"
get 'users', to: "users#index"

post 'guests/receive_guest', to: "guests#receive_guest"
```

**Update 2**

The guide have the following statement:

> When (and if) the user registers or logs in, we delete the guest user
>   and clear the session variable.

It doesn't explain much how and where to do it. I'm guessing I have to call `current_or_guest_user` somewhere again. But I'm not sure where since I'm not that familiar with Devise.

**Update 3**

To make it a bit more clear. This is the steps I want to achieve.

1. User creates a test project.
2. Upon creation of the test project a guest user and session gets created. The guest user should get deleted once the session ends or #3.
3. If the guest user signs up, he /she should get logged in and the test project should get assigned to the new real user.
4. The guest user should get deleted.

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb` file please ?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala I have done that now.

Comment: I have tried the same which you are trying to implement in my machine and it works fine , so may be you are missing something in the additional code that you have written besided that of devise. If it's possible , please remove the above code and post the exact controllers that you have currently . That would be more easy to debug.

Comment: can you update you line `guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)` to like that **guest_user(with_retry = false).reload.try(:destroy)**

Comment: @KhAmmad I can. The problem is however that this if statement `session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id` never becomes true currently. I'm guessing I have to call `current_or_guest_user` somewhere else again, but I'm not sure when or where.

Comment: Did you try this: [rails:3 Devise signup Filter chain halted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered%7D) This may work for Rails4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers skahlert and SsouLlesS. Skipping the warden strategy did help and defining callbacks seems like a clean approach. Beside that I had some other issues.

One was that my custom Devise controllers never got called. Created another question for that: [Rails 4 - devise_for not using custom controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844122/rails-4-devise-for-not-using-custom-controllers). The solution was that I used the wrong url in my modal signup form. My form now looks like this:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path do |f|
```

Then I did as skahlert suggested and removed the [warden strategy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user#authentication-this-may-interfere-with-the-current_user-helper) from my app.

Once my custom devise `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` controller got called I decided to override the create action. It's not completely tested, but it looks like this:

```
# POST /resource
def create
  # Delete guest user and reset session. 
  new_user_from_guest = guest_user
  guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)
  session[:guest_user_id] = nil

  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)

      # Assign the guest users app to the new current user.
      new_user_from_guest.apps.each do |app|
        app.user_id = current_user.id
        app.save!
      end
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location:  after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    # Reset test user if signup fails, I have not tested this part yet. 
    guest_user
    guest_user.apps << new_user_from_guest.apps
    guest_user.save!

    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

Everything seems to work now. Could do some refactoring and possibly try the callback approach that SsouLlesS suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer lacks of explanation, the `loggin_in` method is not being called because you have not defined your callback

In your ApplicationController you need to define and then set the callback like so:

```
define_callbacks :logging_in_user
set_callback :logging_in_user, :before, :transfer_guest_user_actions_to_current_user

def transfer_guest_user_actions_to_current_user
  # todo
end
```

Have you tried to use [devise-guests](https://github.com/cbeer/devise-guests) gem? it implements out of the box this functionality, instead of do it from scratch...

Check this [example](https://github.com/alvinlee1/blacklight/blob/6a24cfcbf1657bdaa388a1e76453220410423db8/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/blacklight-4.0.0/lib/blacklight/controller.rb) controller that is implementing guest login. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into your solution. Seems like a clean way to do it. I created a answer below with how I did it for now, got it to work at least. Feel free to come with suggestion for improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is caused by the guest_user warden strategy referenced in the guide.
Since Devise checks for a valid warden session before logging in, it causes a redirect and a flash message to appear:

```
if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
  flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
  redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

So if you do not strictly need that authenticate! method to work on the guest user, you can simply deactivate that strategy and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. That did help. I have created a full answer of everything I did below. Feel free to add improvements to it if you know a better approach. Thanks!