# Rails 4 - devise_for not using custom controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Devise in my Rails app, and I would like to customise some of it's behaviour. I have read the documentation for `devise_for`. But I can't get it to use my custom controllers. My routs looks like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: "users/sessions",
  registrations: "users/registrations"
}
```

In my `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` I have tried the following:

```
# POST /resource
def create
  puts "I'm here" # never happens!
  super
end
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

**Update**

Here is my file structure:
[image]

**Update 2**

Think I might have found the root of the issue. I render and present my signup form in a Bootstrap modal on another route than the default Devise path.

I present the form on this path:

```
/apps/1/edit
```

And not:

```
users/sign_up
```

If I do sign up on this path `users/sign_up` it works and my methods get called. In my `/apps/1/edit` view I present the forms like this:

```
= render "users/registrations/modal_form"
```

My edit action for my `apps_controller` (the action where I present the signup form) is currently empty:

```
# GET /apps/1/edit
def edit
end
```

The relevant parts of my `users/registrations/modal_form` partial looks like this:

```
.modal.fade#registrations_modal{ tabindex: -1, role: 'dialog', "aria-labelledby" 
  [..]
  = render "users/registrations/new_form"
  [..]
```

And my `users/registrations/new_form` looks like this:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name))  do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  .form-group
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.label :password
    - if @minimum_password_length
      %em
        (#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum)
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-default"

- if current_page?(new_user_registration_path)
  = render "devise/shared/links"
```

I'm not that familiar with Devise. Any ideas on what and where I'm missing something?

Comment: try to place other things than `puts "I'm here"`, try to put `debugger` and see if you app pause at create action? Or just remove `super` to see if action `create` can still work normally?

Comment: Tried to set a breakpoint with the `byebug` gem (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html). But still seems like it never gets called.

Comment: have you tried to restart rails server? where do you put `Users::RegistrationsController`?

Comment: try this `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: @LongNguyen Yeah, I have tried to restart. My controller in in `controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb.

Comment: @PardeepSaini Yeah, that was a typo from me, should be `::` as you points out.

Comment: Show us a files structure for your controllers.

Comment: @Зелёный I have added an image with the file structure to my question.

Comment: Did you try Long Nguyen's suggestion to remove the `super` call to see if it ever parses your code at all? What version of Devise are you using? You do have `class` before `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` in your controller, right?

Comment: What happens if you create a GET action such as `new` in your custom controller and make it output some text like `return "hello"`?

Comment: Your `devise_for` should be at the very top. Is it?

Comment: @Sylar yes, It is at the top.

Comment: @Anders ok now run `rake routes` to see if your custom controller is shown.

Comment: And make sure `resources :users` is in your routes.rb

Comment: @mysmallidea The new action seems to work. Will add some more clarification to how my form looks and see if it helps.

Comment: Think I have found the root of the issue, but haven't found a solution yet. Added another update to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I solved it. The issue was in my `form_for` where I used the wrong route. Instead of using the default `registration_path` as the `url` I instead use:

```
user_registration_path(resource_name)
```

Silly mistake. Ran into another issue, I now keep getting: `ActionController::UnknownFormat` on signup. But it is at least using my custom controllers now.