# Rails 4 - Devise: getting ActionController::UnknownFormat on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a Rails 4.2.3 app where I use Devise for user authentication. I present my signup form in a Bootstrap modal. I have implemented it similar to: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app. On signup I keep getting this error:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 512033ms (ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)
```

And I'm not sur how to fix it.

I use custom controllers for `sessions` and `registrations`. My routes currently looks like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations"}

get 'users/show', to: "users#show"
get 'users', to: "users#index"
```

My new user form looks like this - this gets rendered in a partial that is presented in a Bootstrap modal:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:  user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  .form-group
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.label :password
    - if @minimum_password_length
      %em
        (#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum)
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-default"

- if current_page?(new_user_registration_path)
  = render "devise/shared/links"
```

The app crashes in my `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` `create` method:

```
# POST /resource
def create
  # byebug
  super
end
```

And the url in the browser is the following (looks suspicious!):

```
http://localhost:3000/users.user
```

I have tried adding:

```
respond_to :json, :html
```

At the top of my `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`, but that didn't help.

**Note**

After running the gem `bye bug`the app seems to crash in this method:

```
# The path used after sign up.
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  byebug
  session[:previous_url] || root_path # crashes here
end
```

`session[:previous_url]` returns `"/apps/1/edit"`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here, or anywhere else?

**Sidenote**
I'm simultaneously struggling with another devise issue (they may be related). I have another question for that here: [Rails 4 - Devise, guest users causes filter chain halted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744842/rails-4-devise-guest-users-causes-filter-chain-halted)

Comment: Does changing the url to user_registration_path(resource)) make a difference ?

Comment: @Doon Yes, then my `create` action in `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` never gets called, and it doesn't seem like the user gets created. Instead another action gets called in my ApplicationController: `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`. Can be related to what I'm trying to do with my guest user (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744842/rails-4-devise-guest-users-causes-filter-chain-halted). But yeah, changing the parameter for some reason prevents the action `create`  from getting called.

Comment: @Anders : can you post all the routes please ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change this in your form:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path) do |f|
```

`user_registration_path` does not requires an additional parameter, and you pass the `resource_name` to it, which is equal to `user` in your case. It gets interpreted as the format, and therefore you get url like `http://localhost:3000/users.user` (`user` is set as a format in this case).