# Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have used devise gem and generated views using devise commands with User as the name.

To show the login/logout link in the entire application, I am adding this to my layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if user_session.present? %>
  <%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete' %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :method => 'get' %>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

And This is the home controller that have only index action:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController   
  def index

  end 
end
```

The root is defined to point to `home#index`.

When I am launching the app, it is showing the Login link, upon clicking on the link, I am getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-11-23 23:15:32 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-11-23 23:15:32 +0530
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong. I am not able to figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `HomeController` you may need a `skip_before_filter`. At the top of the `HomeController`, `:skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:index]`

I am not sure skipping the filter all together is the right solution. If that doesn't work for you, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered) may be helpful.