# Angular and Rails with Paypal integration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, paypal-sandbox

I have a rails with angular application.

I already used web payment.especially pay-pal.

When i completed my payment with pay-pal.

I got this error

> {"result":false,"msg":"Invalid API Token."}

In my rails console,

> Started GET
>   "/api/v1/charges/paypal_payment?tx=8R95473028301340P&st=Completed&amt=20.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number="
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-30 11:12:03 +0530 Processing by
>   Api::V1::ChargesController#paypal_payment as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"tx"=>"8R95473028301340P", "st"=>"Completed", "amt"=>"20.00",
>   "cc"=>"USD", "cm"=>"", "item_number"=>""}

Filter chain halted as :auth_request rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: I don't know what i will do :( if any one know help me :)

Comment: see this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered). may be helpful..

Comment: ok i will try govind and thanks a lot :)