# Devise infinite loop Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a weird issue using Ruby on Rails 6 and Devise. After signing in or signing out, the app is on an infinite loop instead of redirecting to the root_path. The root_path does not require any authentication so it shouldn't redirect.

Error logs:

> Started POST "/utilisateurs/connexion" for ::1 at 2023-12-27 10:22:42
> +0100 Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
> "user"=>{"email"=>"email@email.fr",
> "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Je me
> connecte"}   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
> "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 55786],
> ["LIMIT", 1]] after_sign_in_path_for Redirected to
> http://localhost:3000/ **Filter chain halted as**
> **:require_no_authentication rendered or redirected**
>
> Completed 302 Found
> in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 1911)
>
> Started GET "/utilisateurs/" for ::1 at 2023-12-27 10:22:42 +0100

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, 
path: "utilisateurs",
controllers: { 
    sessions: 'users/sessions', 
    registrations: 'users/registrations', 
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
},
:path_names => { :sign_in => 'connexion', :sign_up => 'inscription', :sign_out => 'deconnexion', password: 'retrouver_mot_de_passe', edit: 'finaliser-inscription' }
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :skip_password_validation
    before_validation :check_pseudo, only: [:create, :update]
    validates :pseudo, presence: true
    validates :email, 
                        format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP },
                        presence: true,
                        uniqueness: true

    has_secure_token

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable

    has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify
    has_one :author, dependent: :nullify
    has_one :blitz_score, :dependent => :destroy
    has_one :blitz_conjugaison_score, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :quiz_scores, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :dictee_scores, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :crossword_scores, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :track_subscribers, :dependent => :destroy

    def authenticatable_salt
    return super unless session_token

    "#{super}#{session_token}"
  end

  def invalidate_all_sessions!
    update_attribute(:session_token, SecureRandom.hex)
  end

    protected

    def check_pseudo
        unless self.pseudo.present?
            self.pseudo = self.email.split("@")[0] if self.email.present?
        end
    end

    def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation
    super
  end
end
```

Note that I don't require the password to create an account. Visitors give their email first, then they can fill in their `pseudo` and `password` after they confirm their account.

Sessions controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    layout 'blank'

  protected
    
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        root_path
    end 
    
    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        root_path
    end
end
```

Devise initializer:

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12

  config.reconfirmable = false

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 6..128

  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  config.reset_password_within = 24.hours

  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Development config:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.active_storage.service = :local

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
    
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

    config.i18n.default_locale = :fr

    config.after_initialize do
        Bullet.enable = true
        Bullet.bullet_logger = true
        Bullet.unused_eager_loading_enable = false
        Bullet.raise = false
    end
end
```

I tried the following without success:

- Removed the Devise custom controllers
- Clear cookies + cache in development and restart the server
- Removed the `skip_password_validation` in User model
- Started the rails server on a different port

Not sure if this could be the origin of the issue, but I am working on several other rails apps. I fire them separately using `rails s` and the server is on localhost:3000. Maybe this could mess up with the sessions or else?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's a Devise method, you can find it here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L103

Comment: If I add 'skip_before_action :require_no_authentication' in the Session controller, I get an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error. Also, I don't manually use the require_no_authentication method, it's just Devise performing its own logic.

Comment: In my route file:
root to: "home#index"

Home controller:
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 layout 'full', except: :formations

 def index
        end
end

Comment: I don't have before_action :authenticate_user! neither in `ApplicationController` nor `HomeController`

Comment: There's multiple hits on Google for this error message. Have you looked at any of them? I am pretty sure one of them will solve your issue. Since there is no minimally reproducible code in this question, it will be very hard for people to solve your issue otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631432/rails3-devise-signup-filter-chain-halted-as-require-no-authentication-rendered

Comment: It looks like the problem you're facing in your Ruby on Rails 6 application with Devise might be connected to how sessions are handled or how the application handles redirects. The issue seems to occur because even though your root_path doesn't need authentication, it's still causing problems with redirection.

Comment: Yes indeed @AztecCodes, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Casper they offer to skip the "require_no_authentication" before_action but if I do that I have an authenticity token issue. Also, when I disconnect the custom Devise controllers, the issue is still there. So, I assume the issue is not coming from Controllers?

Comment: Also, note that when I sign in, in another rails app in development, I tend to have sometimes the same issue. So I guess it's a problem related to the sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the issue was related to the service-worker.js of the PWA implementation.

Somehow, Devise was redirecting to the service-worker.js, resulting in an infinite redirect loop.